# User ID Primary Key Length

Tags: sql, database, database-design, primary-key, primary-key-design

I am designing a database with multiple tables like users, content, etc. I want to allot id to each row in the tables.

So what are the criteria to generate an unique id for each row in each table. And should I make the id in auto increment mode?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, in general.

Comment: `Auto increment` is indeed what you need

Comment: @jarlh What should be the length of the id

Comment: Depends on the size of the table.

Comment: What if it is difficult to determine the size? For instance in my content table, the content will be added frequently

Comment: For example Google uses 21 digits for user id. So is it preferable to have a fixed length id like 1000001, 1000002 and so on or normal 1, 2, 3

Comment: How many records do you expect to have in your tables? Sql-Server, MySql, Oracle and probably a lot of other databases int data type can hold values between -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) and 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647). I don't imagine you will need a much bigger number, but if you will you can use BIGINT.

Comment: To answer your other question - I think it's better to go with a simple 1, 2, 3... instead of 10000001, 10000002... However most auto-increment columns will enable you to choose a starting number that is bigger then 1, if you want to.

Comment: @ZoharPeled what would be the difference in using 1,2,3 or 10000001 as the primary key ?

Comment: no real difference, it's just a personal preference.